# Laravel nested `hasOne` relationship with `where` clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have `Shop` model which has multiple `Content` entries:

```
    public function contents(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Content::class);
    }
```

And I had `hasOne` relationship with one specific type of content like this:

```
    public function widgetContent(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Content::class)->where('type', Content::WIDGET);
    }
```

It was working fine but I moved `Content`'s type into a new model called `ContentType`, and removed the `type` field from `Content` model, but instead added another `hasOne` relationship via `content_type_id` field.

Now, I'm trying to achieve the same `widgetContent` relationship but I can't. Here's my code:

```
    public function widgetContent(): HasOne
    {
        return $this
            ->hasOne(Content::class)
            ->whereHas('contentType', fn ($q) => $q->where('type', ContentType::WIDGET));
    }
```

What should I do to achieve this? Also, if this is not the best practice (that's how I feel), what is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a closure and use that in stead. So you would still have the relationship like this:

```
public function content(): HasOne
    {
        return $this
            ->hasOne(Content::class);
    }
```

But then you add a closure in your model:

```
public function getWidgetContent()
    {
        return $this->content()->whereHas('contentType', function(Builder $q){
        $q->where('type', ContentType::WIDGET)
        })->get();
}
```

And then you just call the closure function when you need the results.